# Matlab index out of range

Tags: arrays, matlab, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

I seem to be getting an index out of range error when I run the program. It seems to occur on line 19 and relates to the vec2 variable. I don't understand why this is happening, however, because vec2 is initialized the same way as vec. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

```
N = 6;
vec2 = ones(1,N);
vec = ones(1,N) * -1;


for i = 1:N
  num = input('Enter an integer: ');

  if num >= 0
      vec(i) = num;
  else
      vec2(i) = num;
  end

  if sign(vec(i)) == -1
      vec(i) = [];
  end

  if sign(vec2(i)) == 1
      vec2(i) = [];
  end
end

save pos.dat vec -ascii;
save neg.dat vec2 -ascii;
```

Comment: Each time you do `vec2(i) = []`, `vec2` has one fewer element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing could be illustrated as follows:

```
vec = [1, 2, 3];% assuming a given vector vec, length = 3
vec(2) = 5; % no problem 
vec = [1, 5, 3];
vec(2) = [];% vec length is 2
vec = [1, 3];
vec(3) = 10; % not allowed 
%% index out of range since the length of vec is 2
```

**Alternative**

- Instead of removing the cells at first place
- fill them with `nan`
- then remove all cell with `nan`

The code is as follows

```
N = 6;
vec2 = ones(1,N);
vec = ones(1,N) * -1;


for i = 1:N
  num = input('Enter an integer: ');

  if num >= 0
      vec(i) = num;
  else
      vec2(i) = num;
  end

  if sign(vec(i)) == -1
      vec(i) = nan;
  end

  if sign(vec2(i)) == 1
      vec2(i) = nan;
  end
end
%% remove nan
vec = vec(~isnan(vec));
vec2 = vec2(~isnan(vec2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are doing this

```
  vec(i) = [];
```

and this

```
  vec2(i) = [];
```

after every iteration the index i is increasing whereas the vec or vec2 are decreasing. So after 3 iteration vec or vec2 is becoming zero in length .
So btw what are you trying to achieve with these codes.

```
   if sign(vec(i)) == -1
    vec(i) = [];
   end

   if sign(vec2(i)) == 1
    vec2(i) = [];
   end
```

If you remove the above code it will work fine. It would be better to know what your goals are so to suggest alternate solution.